# How to get execution time of c program?

Tags: c, time, execution

I am using clock function for my c program to print execution time of current program.I am getting wrong time in output.I want to display time in seconds,milliseconds and microseconds.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    clock_t start = clock(); 
    sleep(3);
    clock_t end = clock(); 
    double time_taken = (double)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds 

    printf("time program took %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken); 
    return 0; 
} 


time ./time
time program took 0.081000 seconds to execute
real    0m3.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

I expect output around 3 seconds however it display wrong.
As you see **if I run this program using Linux command time** I am getting correct time,I want to display same time using my c program.

Comment: Try [POSIX `clock_gettime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html).

Comment: It is measuring the CPU time consumed by the program execution. I would imagine the sleeping time is not counted (as the process is suspended during this time). The mentioned `clock_gettime` is measuring the "global" time. So it depends what exactly you want to measure here.

Comment: How I can use that in program @EugeneSh.@pmg

Comment: Good luck with the microseconds accuracy.

Comment: See also [What specifically are wall-clock time, user CPU time, and system CPU time in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335920/) — and also POSIX [`clock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html).

Comment: Can anybody update my code to get proper execution time of current program?

Comment: I am not getting your answer .Could you please modified my sample code or give any sample code  with required output. thanks @chqrlie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, the `clock()` function retrieves CPU time, not elapsed clock time as the name confusingly may induce people to believe.

Here is the language from the C Standard:

> **7.27.2.1 The `clock` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <time.h>
> clock_t clock(void);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `clock` function determines the processor time used.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `clock` function returns the implementation’s best approximation to the processor time used by the program since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related only to the program invocation. To determine the time in seconds, the value returned by the clock function should be divided by the value of the macro `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. If the processor time used is not available, the function returns the value `(clock_t)(−1)`. If the value cannot be represented, the function returns an unspecified value.

To retrieve the elapsed time, you should use one of the following:

- the `time()` function with a resolution of 1 second
- the `timespec_get()` function which may be more precise, but might not be available on all systems
- the `gettimeofday()` system call available on linux systems
- the `clock_gettime()` function.

See [What specifically are wall-clock-time, user-cpu-time, and system-cpu-time in UNIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335920/what-specifically-are-wall-clock-time-user-cpu-time-and-system-cpu-time-in-uni) for more information on this subject.

Here is a modified version using `gettimeoday()`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main() {
    struct timeval start, end;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    sleep(3);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    double time_taken = end.tv_sec + end.tv_usec / 1e6 -
                        start.tv_sec - start.tv_usec / 1e6; // in seconds

    printf("time program took %f seconds to execute\n", time_taken);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
time program took 3.005133 seconds to execute
```